# auto complete search suggestion pushing down the other content

Tags: css

This is my web site with search http://clients.onebricktech.com/whenisit/search.php?keywords=1Trades1%20Plumbing
If I search anything the content pushing down by search suggestion keyword.

Comment: Please don't ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post a relevant code example as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute` in the table that contains the search term textbox. Then you will need to adjust the table margin left property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the suggestion box out of the flow with `position: absolute` though I actually like the functionality as it is TBH.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
position: absolute
```

in the ajaxresults tag, this should work

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this

```
<div style="float:left; position: relative">
    <form id="cityForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="true" name="cityChanged">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="keywords">
        <input type="text" data-default="146" onblur="this.style.color='#318d00'" value="Trivandrum, 13" style="width: 150px; color: rgb(49, 141, 0); display: inline-block;" onkeyup="city_completer()" onclick="javacript:this.select();this.style.color='#000'" class="city_state" id="city_stater" name="city_state" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
    <div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 35px; width: 120px; border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); display: block;" id="ajaxcity"><div><div class="citySuggest"><a onclick="copyToCityBox('Caledon Village, ON');document.getElementById('citySelect').submit()" href="javascript:void()">Caledon Village, ON</a></div><div class="citySuggest"><a onclick="copyToCityBox('Caledon, ON');document.getElementById('citySelect').submit()" href="javascript:void()">Caledon, ON</a></div><div class="citySuggest"><a onclick="copyToCityBox('Courtice, ON');document.getElementById('citySelect').submit()" href="javascript:void()">Courtice, ON</a></div></div></div>
</div>
```